# Dynamic Filename with Grunt Uglify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am trying to set the version in the filename with Grunt Uglify, but it doesn't accept anything other than a string literal.

How can I replace "VERSION" dynamically by using a variable (e.g. `${VERSION}`), or better yet, a command line argument?

```
grunt.initConfig({

  uglify: {
    min: {
       options: {}
      ,files: {
        "jquery.project-VERSION.min.js" : [ "jquery.project.js", "modules/*.js" ]
      }
    }
    ,dev: {
       options: {
        beautify: {
          width: 80
        }
      }
      ,files: {
        "jquery.project-VERSION.dev.js" : [ "jquery.project.js", "modules/*.js" ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates

Comment: @cartant Thanks, that worked.  If you want to make it an answer and give the actual example snippet I will gladly accept it.

Comment: No worries. Probably easier for you to post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) though.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment by @cartant, this can be done with a Grunt template, e.g. `<%= version %>`

So in my case it was

```
grunt.initConfig({

   version: 1.2.3    

  ,uglify: {
    min: {
       options: {}
      ,files: {
        "jquery.project-<%= version %>.min.js" : [ "jquery.project.js", "modules/*.js" ]
      }
    }
    ,dev: {
       options: {
        beautify: {
          width: 80
        }
      }
      ,files: {
        "jquery.project-<%= version %>.dev.js" : [ "jquery.project.js", "modules/*.js" ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Ref: [Grunt > Configuring Tasks > Templates](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates)